# How to use this FFT code with a variable sine wave size and integers instead of shorts?

Tags: java, integer, transform, fft

http://www.koders.com/java/fid168F68D8D019CF9A4F17CA8AFEE102F8BE3B2C28.aspx?s=FFT#L21

2 part question, really.  My understanding of FFT's is pretty general.

1)  The code seems straight forward enough.  But the solution I'm looking for requires a variable data array size (still will be a power of 2).  So how should I change the sine wave that's used here?  I see it's a static 1024 size sinewave that is clearly defined.  How could I use a dynamic size of the real data array to generate a proper sinewave?

2)  Also, the solution I'm looking for requires the use of ints instead of shorts like the example linked.  As in the input data array will be an array of ints.  What modifications of this code would be needed?

Thanks in advance for all your help.

Answer (score 0):

1. If you need a variable size array, just use an `ArrayList` to insert your values. The code should be easy to adjust to accomodate this.
2. To change from a short to an int, simply change them all to ints. A short is just a 2 byte integer, instead of int which is 4 bytes.